# how to add sliding lines inside of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hi I am struggling with a jquery problem what i need is, sliding lines inside of borders of an image. There are four lines and I want them to slide inside the border when the page is loaded. The first line should slide down to up; the second one left-to-right; the third one top-to-down and the fourth from right to left.

I hope that my question is clear.

[image]

(the mentioned lines are red)

Comment: Yep - that's clear.  Can you post the code you've already tried and explain what happened?

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's [.ainmate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) method

Comment: actually I don't have an accurate code for that.I can just creat the line by z-index property. but don't know how to slide them.

Comment: Show us what you've already got - the code.

Comment: You might be able to use CSS transitions

Comment: what I wanna do is, to slide the lines respectively in the link: http://jsfiddle.net/QL3wT/2/ Each color should slide respectively not at the same time. I need jquery script code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS to do this. [Here is a pure CSS way](http://jsfiddle.net/6HLhY/1/) of performing this animation onload, by using `keyframes`. Unless you want to support older browsers, this method should work.

Comment: +1. A bit more difficult, but animations will go smoother (with larger animations).

Comment: People say this, yet I notice that the animation is choppy, and slow, compared to a normal jQuery Animate.

Comment: I find that mobile devices animate my menus a lot faster and smoother. Might be device/animation sensative

Comment: It is device/browser sensitive. Some browsers/devices don't handle css driven animations as well as others. In my experience the best way to create smooth animations across all browsers and devices is to hardware accelerate the animations. So instead of top:10px you would use transform:translate3d(0,10px,0). This method usually eliminates the choppines @WASasquatch is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show the first two, you can do the other two

```
function slideLine1(){ $('#line1').animate({width: '100%'}, 1000, slideLine2); }
function slideLine2(){ $('#line2').animate({width: '100%'}, 1000, slideLine3); }
```

This will work. However, you can do this with 1 function, calling itself, and an `i` variable. That will be up to you.

There are other methods to do, this is a very basic example. A tip: Look into jQuery chaining.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f8jDp/) which uses only css.

It basically uses `@keyframes` to solve the problem.

Comment: This is very nice. But Maybe I could not refer to the problem correctly. The lines move through inside the image. But I want them to move from out toward inside. http://jsfiddle.net/QL3wT/2/